# What is the value decimal UNIT of the gas censor MQ-135 in arduino?

Tags: android, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm setting up a M135 gas censor in my arduino project, and it now display the decimal value of the censor, din my concern is there a unit of the value of the decimal? like for example unit of the Weight is kg, in M135 gas censor, can anybody help me know the unit?

Answer (score 0):

Information like that can be retrieved from the part's datasheet.

https://www.olimex.com/Products/Components/Sensors/Gas/SNS-MQ135/resources/SNS-MQ135.pdf

No there is no unit. MQ-135 has different sensitivity for different gases.

It has to be calibrated using a known concentration of the gas you want to detect. Of course the sensor cannot distinguish between various gases so sensing a concentration of one gas while a significant but unknown concentration of another gas is present is not going to work.

The SI unit of weight is Newton btw. Not kilogram. Kilogram is the unit of mass.